# SQL insert with not exists loading all records instead of 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm testing out a concept but having an issue with understanding why this isn't working. I know there are workarounds but want to know why this is not working.

There are 4 lines in a table called #test, all with a key off 10002677818269286. When selecting from the table, I'm saying load one if it does not alreay exist in the table. What I'm hoping is that it inserts the first record and rejects the rest. But instead all get loaded. Here is the code

```
INSERT INTO #final_phone_t
(batch_id, ExternalID, CompanyCode, SeqNumber, PhoneType, AreaCode, Number,Num2)
SELECT
    tp.batch_id, tp.ExternalID, tp.CompanyCode, tp.SeqNumber, tp.PhoneType,
    tp.AreaCode,tp.Number,
    CONVERT(varchar(7), tp.ExternalID) + RTRIM(tp.AreaCode) + RTRIM(tp.Number)
FROM #test tp
WHERE not EXISTS(    
    SELECT 1   
    FROM #final_phone_t fp
    WHERE 10002677818269286
   = Num2
)   
ORDER BY tp.ExternalID, tp.PhoneType ASC
```

Comment: If I run the following part , I get three as the result which is what I would expect SELECT 1
FROM #final_phone_t fp WHERE 10002677818269286 = Num2

Comment: Try to link the internal exists with the main field CONVERT(varchar(7), tp.ExternalID) + RTRIM(tp.AreaCode) + RTRIM(tp.Number) instead of your value.

Comment: It is within an exists clause. All that is doing is including all records where that condition inside the exists returns any data, it is not limiting the number being returned, you would want the limit to be on the outer query, not the inner query.

Answer (score 1):

The `EXISTS` keyword merely tests if rows exist for the specified condition. As pointed out in the comments, you need to restrict the row set in the outer `SELECT` query. Since you expect only the first row to be inserted, you can add a `TOP 1` to limit the results of the query to 1 row. Query is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO #final_phone_t 
            (batch_id, 
             externalid, 
             companycode, 
             seqnumber, 
             phonetype, 
             areacode, 
             number, 
             num2) 
SELECT TOP 1 tp.batch_id, 
             tp.externalid, 
             tp.companycode, 
             tp.seqnumber, 
             tp.phonetype, 
             tp.areacode, 
             tp.number, 
             CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), tp.externalid) 
             + Rtrim(tp.areacode) + Rtrim(tp.number) 
FROM   #test tp 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                  FROM   #final_phone_t fp 
                  WHERE  num2 = 10002677818269286 
                 --Column name on the left, literal on the right 
                 ) 
ORDER  BY tp.externalid, 
          tp.phonetype ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO #final_phone_t
  (batch_id, ExternalID, CompanyCode, SeqNumber, PhoneType, AreaCode, Number,Num2)
SELECT Top 1//but here you are selecting all records this is the actual statement which is inserting into DB so use Select Top 1 here as well.
  tp.batch_id, tp.ExternalID, tp.CompanyCode, tp.SeqNumber, tp.PhoneType,
  tp.AreaCode,tp.Number,
  CONVERT(varchar(7), tp.ExternalID) + RTRIM(tp.AreaCode) + RTRIM(tp.Number)
FROM #test tp
WHERE not EXISTS(    
  SELECT 1  //Here for comparison you are selecting only one record.  
  FROM #final_phone_t fp
  WHERE 10002677818269286
  = Num2
)   
ORDER BY tp.ExternalID, tp.PhoneType ASC
```

Comment: Actually I notice using Top 1 would only work in this example. If I had more records and was no limiting the query to one  record, it would still only return top 1. For example, say as well as the 4 records above, I had two other different records, top 1 would return 1 as opposed to 3.

Comment: top 1 will only return first record whether they are same or different.

Comment: also remove top 1 from outer select